# TFS Powershell cmdlet not working in ISE

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am unable to run the following command in Powershell ISE but these exact same command works just fine in a regular Powershell console.

```
Get-TfsServer -name http://mytfsserver:8080
```

I tried adding the Snap-in from the ISE console but it did not help. I even added it to the Script Pane in ISE but it did not help.

I am on Win8 & TFS Power Tools 2012.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be bitness issue.  IIRC the TFPT PowerShell module is x86 only.  It could be that it is working in an x86 PowerShell console but failing in a 64-bit ISE.

Comment: Is there any way to check what version (bitness) of Powershell I am running?

Comment: Interesing, I can't call (or import) these cmdlets in anything but a 32-bit console (or ISE). Then again, my version of TFPT may be a bit old.

Comment: Just checked and I have the latest TFPT from 11/29/2012.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you added pssnapin microsoft.teamfoundation.powershell in to the powershell ISE..

The ISE should be x64 bit. Since this snapin works in x64 bit only.

we dont have any command to check the bitness. but while opening the ISE itself it will show the bitness (if it is x86.)

x64 bit ISE will not show the bitness version.

kudos